# How to check the logical equals condtion in XSLT?

Tags: xslt, logical-operators

I have this simple test in XSLT

```
<xsl:if test="isTrue = 'false'">
```

but I can't figure out how to do the logical equals operator here. I know `<` is `&lt;` and `>` is `&gt;` so what is the logical equals operator for XSLT? I tried `&eq;` `&et;` `==` and `=` , or is it that for XSLT you can only compare numbers?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`=` [should work just fine](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-tests)

e.g. This input Xml

```
<xml>
    <SomeElement>1</SomeElement>
    <SomeAttribute attr="true" />
</xml>
```

Through this transform:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/xml">
        <xsl:if test="SomeElement=1">
            Some Element is 1
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="SomeAttribute/@attr='true'">
            Some Attribute is true
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Returns

```
Some Element is 1
Some Attribute is true
```

As expected. Possibly the error is in the path selector, not in the `test` ?